# Visual Studio debugging behaving very strange

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Whenever I debug in visual studio my current execution line goes down and then sometimes back up! I thought it was because of some threading issue but its not, I also cannot debug about 70% of the variables, When I hover mouse over a certain variable nothing comes up or it says memory cannot be read, I am desperately trying to solve this, what could be causing this issue?

I hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: It might be that you are builing in release mode and activating code optimization. make sure to build in Debug mode

Comment: I am building in debug mode with no optimizations at all :(